# Is Jack-O-Lantern part of the DC Universe, or the Marvel Universe?

Tags: marvel, dc, comics

I was reading the entire comic book series of **Venomverse** (i.e. #1-5) which is literally the introduction of an entire *Venom Universe* and a Venom clan known as **The Resistance**.

In the first few pages of Vol. 1, though, it introduces a villain known as **Jack-O-Lantern**.

*Now, isn't Jack-O-Lantern part of the **DC Universe** as opposed to the **Marvel Universe** in which Venom battles against him?*

Massive DC fans would surely know about the **Crisis Trilogy** (composed of three comic book series):

- *Crisis on Infinite Earths* (April 1985 — March 1986);
- *Infinite Crisis* (December 2005 — June 2006); and
- *Final Crisis* (May 2008 — January 2009).

This is because around the time from the beginning of the trilogy, an entire DC Universe was being constructed. Given that there were so many different variations of DC characters, it grew into a **DC Multiverse**, I guess, but here it did not. There became a mainstream DC Comics universe.

---

But that is what confuses me. In the first comic book of the trilogy, I remember stumbling upon Jack-O-Lantern amongst a group of heroes that tried to save the world. I don't remember which country they were from, but he was definitely included in the DC Universe.

But now he is in the Marvel universe? (Pursuant to Venomverse). I think he looks different in the comic as opposed to when I first read about him, but doing some research, it turns out the first appearance of Jack-O-Lantern was in **Peter Parker, The Spectacular Spider-Man #56**.

So, he was first introduced in the Marvel Universe, then introduced in the DC Universe, and now he is back in the Marvel universe — and Spider-Man and Venom are *enemies*, so why are they fighting the same guy? Even later on in *Venomverse*, we get an idea of Venom's relationship with Spider-Man, and they aren't really what you would call "friends".

In fact, Venom *murdered* Jack-O-Lantern, and this was before he was teleported into the Venom Universe!

---

<sub>*Please Note*: I have not collected the other Venom editions just yet, so if there are any spoilers, please let me know.</sub>

Comment: I've edited out the second question as it doesn't seem to be a part of the main question you are asking here, if you still want to know the answer you can ask it as a new question. You have a lot of text that could, or could not, be related to the second question as well, I wasn't sure so left the majority of it alone. As for the [aliens] tag I don't think that is appropriate here.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot ok. Thank you for that. I will be sure to add some pictures as well after looking at the answer.

Comment: “ Massive DC fans would surely know about the Crisis Trilogy” — would medium-sized DC fans know about it? How about deceptively small ones.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite yes, perhaps. It is just that the first comic book series in the Crisis Trilogy was in the 1980—1990s. So, now, in 2018, I thought what I thought. Are you a DC fan?

Comment: There are several instances of heroes/villains in DC and Marvel that share the same name but are completely different characters.  For example, Captain Marvel, Apocalypse (villain in superman, first mutant in Marvel), Quicksilver (mutant in Marvel, speedster in DC), Scarecrow (villains in both universes), Lizard, and Spiderman (villain of Shazam, and obviously hero of Marvel).

Comment: Why *wouldn't* Venom and Spider-Man fight the same person?
"Maxim 29: 
The enemy of my enemy is my enemy's enemy. No more. No less."

Comment: @user477343: naw, more of a Marvel guy. I liked Kingdom Come! Although I understand huge DC fans would get more out of all the references in it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They're different people (actually different sets of people)

#### [Jack O'Lantern (DC Comics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_O%27Lantern_(DC_Comics))

Three Irish heroes given mystical powers by a fairy's magic lantern.

[image: Jack O'Lantern (DC Comics)]

#### [Jack O'Lantern (Marvel Comics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_O%27Lantern_(Marvel_Comics))

Four American villains, mostly enemies of Spider-Man and Captain America, and in some cases wearing powered costumes made for them by Hobgoblin.

[image: Jack O'Lantern (Marvel Comics)]

Comment: Hah, well, this answers my first question (and also answers which Jack-O-Lantern was in the comic: **Jason Macendale**). If only I typed "Jack-O-Lantern (DC Comics)" instead of for "Marvel Comics"... However, you do not answer my second question, but if I did not reach my daily voting limit, I would have upvoted :)

Comment: @rojomoke - Macendale was the Jack O'Lantern before he was the Hobgoblin; at that point, Hobgoblin did not supply the costume; I'm not sure if the first person to replace him was equipped by a Hobgoblin either.